Using Business app, Can I read/access public page post and comments?
based on the <Page Public Content Access> feature and this doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access/
I understand after Business app approval can access  public page post and comments. I would like to know how to try this feature before going live or app approval ?

Quote from that very page: "While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app. If you want the app to be able to access public content on other Pages, you must submit this feature for review. Once you set your app to live mode, it will not be able to see any Page public content without this feature."
